# Unity Timeline character transform initial values

Tags: unity, animation, cutscene

I'm trying to make a runtime cutscene in Unity using the Timeline editor. I have a humanoid character with an animation controller, track and a cinemachine track set-up in the playable. The timeline starts playing onTriggerEnter() through script. Initially I applied the track offsets and the timeline plays perfectly in the editor but in play mode the player swaps to random positions in the world and it looks really ugly. So I changed the track offsets to scene offsets and it's almost works perfectly except that the position and rotation of the character are relative to the input just before the character enters the trigger (all input is disabled on trigger entered).

What I intend to do is set a default position and rotation to the character at the beginning of the timeline. Is there any way to achieve that within the timeline editor, if not how else could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my issue. The problem was 'root motion' was enabled on the character's animator. Disabling that during the timeline worked just fine with the provided track offsets.